# Title running off the page!

Tags: line-breaking, text-decorations

I haven't had this problem before so I'm not quite sure what's happening, but my title is running off to the right side of the page. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{assymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{outlines}

\begin{document}
\title{\vspace{0.9in}\underline{Chapter 13 - Chromosomal Rearrangements \& Changes in Chromosome Number}}
\date{}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-1.5cm}

%some text

\end{document}
```

Is my title too long or is there a genuine problem with my code? I don't think the title length is a factor as it should then just go to the next line. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\underline` doesn't admit line breaks; you could use `\uline` from the [ulem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem) package instead. Load the package in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
```

(`normalem` will prevent `\emph` commands from showing up as underlined instead of as italics) and then:

```
\uline{Chapter 13 - Chromosomal Rearrangements \& Changes in Chromosome Number}}
```

Comment: Make sure you load `ulem` with the `[normalem]` option, otherwise your `\emph` commands will show up as underlined instead of italics.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Thanks. I was about to add that to my answer. I'll do it anyway.

Comment: & Alan Munn: Although I don't really use \emph for italics (I use \textit instead), thanks for letting me know!