# Break line in \textbf{} in \uline{} element

Tags: line-breaking

I have such construction in my document.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

\uline{ Example text \textbf{bold example text huge long with many lines that would not work correctly, but should}.}

\end{document}
```

If execute this code, result will be long line. Is there any way how to handle it correctly and separate `\textbf{}` block. I have googled and read different answers, but still did not find something helpful. Maybe this construction should be rewritten in more correct way ?

I am using TexMaker -> Quick Build, before I have used ShareLatex, problem is the same in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be accomplished by "subdividing" the long string and underlining
each segment separately.  there are (at least) two different approaches:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

\uline{ Example text }\textbf{\uline{bold example text huge long with many lines
 that would not work correctly, but should}\uline{.}}

\uline{ Example text }{\bfseries\uline{bold example text huge long with many lines
 that would not work correctly, but should}\uline{.}}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

since you don't want a bold period, that has to be handled separately.

note the documented restriction on hyphenation:

> Every word is typeset in an underlined box, so automatic hyphenation
>   is disabled, but explicit discretionary hyphens (`\-`) will still be
>   obeyed.

there are other documented complications as well, so reference to the
package manual is advised.

a related situation is described in [Title running off the page!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14478/579).

Comment: It seems to work, I am testing it just right now. But what I can do with `\uline` it doesn't work correctly sometimes and words aren't broken.

Comment: "words aren't broken" is a documented limitation.  see the manual (`texdoc ulem`, p.4); i'll add the info to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `soul` instead (apart from avoiding underlining, of course).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\ul{Example text \textbf{bold example text huge long with many lines that would not work correctly,
but should}.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reasons it didn't work with russian text. I guess with English text it might work perfectly.